# RabbitMQ set_permissions syntax

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I've installed `rabbitmq` and it's running.

I've successfully `add_user` as well as `add_vhost`. But in the next step of the documentation it says to `set_permissions` and I'm failing.

I get `Error: could not recognise command` when I enter the following:

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p myvhost myuser ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

(this is copy and pasted verbatim from the documentation so it seems a bit ridiculous that it doesn't work.. And 'recognise' being misspelled in the error msg isn't helping)

My question is what does `".*" ".*" ".*"` mean/stand for?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html#set_permissions)

> set_permissions [-p vhostpath] {user} {conf} {write} {read}
>
> vhostpath - The name of the virtual host to which to grant the user
> access, defaulting to /.
>
> user - The name of the user to grant access to the specified virtual
> host.
>
> conf -  A **regular expression** matching resource names for which the
> user is granted configure permissions.
>
> write -  **A regular expression** matching resource names for which the
> user is granted write permissions.
>
> read - A **regular expression** matching
> resource names for which the user is granted read permissions.

To answer your question specifically, `".*" ".*" ".*"` is a set of three regular expressions (applying to configure, write, and read) which will [match all](http://regexr.com/) the permissions available (`.` will match any character, `*` will match any number of the preceding character)

Comment: What does word "resource" exactly mean? Exchange? Queue? Routing key? Or all of them?

Answer (score 18):

.* means you have full permissions
^$ means you don't have any permissons

Comment: Thanks, was looking for the "no permissions" syntax.